# why using "$$" (two dollar sign) instead of just "$" (single dollar sign) for blank line removal in Makefile?

Tags: regex, sed, makefile, gnu-make

I met some old Makefile script which was designed to delete blank lines using the sed command. The code itself is pretty easy and straightforward.

```
sed -i -e '/^[ \t]*$$/ d'
```

I know the `^[ \t]*$` part just indicates that a line starts with space or tab then repeated zero or more times until the end of the line. I didn't quite understand why there is an additional "$" sign at the end of the regular expression. 
I also tried using only single $ sign. It seems that the same effects can be achieved.

```
sed -i -e '/^[ \t]*$/ d'
```

Then what is the purpose of using the double-dollar sign in this case?

-------------------------Additional comments--------------------

It's my fault that I didn't mention that it comes from a Makefile. I naively thought it would be the same thing no matter it is inside or outside a Makefile. The command is like this:

`RM_BLANK: org_file
          @cpp  org_file | sed -e 's/   */ /g' > file
          @sed -i -e '/^[ \t]*$$/ d' file`

org_file is the file that contains a lot of blanks lines.

It (I mean with `$$`) behaves exactly as hek2mgl's answer below has predicted when used outside a Makefile if the `sed` command is performed directly on org_file. It only deletes lines that end with a `$` and leaves the empty lines without `$` intact. But when used in a Makefile environment, it simply deletes blank lines that don't have a `$` at the end of line. I think it might have to do with the Makefile convention. Would someone help with this puzzle?

Comment: `$$` still matches end of line (twice!). It’s an oversight that didn’t actually cause a problem.

Comment: @Bohemian  I see. But matching end of line once would be enough, right? Is there any safety reason for doing this?

Comment: @Bohemian I admit it took me a while, but that's not an oversight

Comment: Is this code by any chance part of a Makefile?

Comment: Since `\S` is the dual of `\s` an alternative solution is `sed -i '/\S/!d' file`

Comment: @melpomene yes. It is in a Makefile.

Comment: @melpomene. It's indeed from a Makefile. It's my fault. I rephrased the question. Would you please have a look at the question again?

Comment: @melpomene Thank you very much. I think it is the reason for using a double dollar sign.

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** a safety mechanism, it's just part of the regular expression. In basic posix regular expressions, which `sed` is using, the `$` has no special meaning, except of when being used at the end of the pattern. Meaning the expression matches lines which optionally contain tabs and which end with a literal `$`. If you remove the second `$`, the `sed` command would remove lines which don't end with a `$` as well.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax agrees: "*`$` also acts as a special character only at the end of the regular expression or subexpression (that is, before `\)` or `\|`), and its use at the end of a subexpression is not portable.*"

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes. You absolutely are right. The first dollar sign is a literal "$" without any special meaning, and the second dollar sign indicates end of line. I tried it outside the Makefile, and it behaves as what you've predicted. But inside the Makefile, it deletes blank lines. I think it's my fault that I didn't mention this line was found in a Makefile. I am still a little bit confused.

Comment: @hek2mgl I rephrased the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm not a Makefile pro. I suggest to wait for @melpomene to return and give an answer on this

Comment: That's fine. You already helped a lot.